# how to insert array of questions in mariadb using senecajs(microservice toolkit) in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, microservices

```
Questions = [question1, question2, question3,....question n];
```

how to do this in nodejs using senecajs or any other ORM.